# How to pass array to Post method in this.collection.create in backbone?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js in my mvc application and I have a scenario where I have to pass an array to my Post method in Rest API . I am trying to set an array property in my model and then calling this.collection.create(model). I am using properties of models like this

```
defaults: {
            Address: '',
            City: '',
            State: '',
            Zip: '',
            AddressArray: []
        }
```

and trying to call Post method as

```
    e.models[0].set({ 'AddressArray': e.models});
    this.collection.create(e.models[0]);
```

Here e.models[0] is my object of my model and e.models is an array of models. The set property sets array address but then on create it is giving this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Please guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["How" to save an entire collection in Backbone.js - Backbone.sync or jQuery.ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879138/how-to-save-an-entire-collection-in-backbone-js-backbone-sync-or-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

The error just means you've created a self-referencing object (such can't possibly be serialized to JSON).  Ie, you've done the equivalent of this:

```
var x = {};
x['test'] = x;
JSON.stringify(x); // TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

You could create a copy of the model first, using `toJSON`, so that the object doesn't reference itself:

```
var json = e.models[0].toJSON();
json['AddressArray'] = e.models[0].attributes;
this.collection.create(json);
```

But this doesn't quite make sense, because `.attributes` refers to the model's properties, so all you're doing is creating a duplicate of the model under `AddressArray`, ie, if model is say `{ prop: "val", prop2: "val2" }`, then you just end up with:

```
{
    prop: "val",
    prop2: "val2",
    AddressArray: {
        prop: "val",
        prop2: "val2",
    }
}
```

Either way, you can't convert an object that references itself to JSON; and serialization is required save a model to the server by calling `Collection.create`.

Comment: Hi dbaseman you are right. But actualy I have array of models at client side which I want to send on server side in Post method. Please guide How will I send array of models to Post method of Rest API as I don't have much idea of backbone.js.

Comment: @touseefkhan4pk see this question, where the accepted answer is to create another model that contains your collection, and override its `toJSON` method:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6879138/1001985