# How to send Array of models to Post API method in backbone?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js in my mvc application and I have a scenario where I have to pass an array to my Post method in Rest API. I am trying to send an array of models and then calling `this.collection.create(model)`. I am trying to call the Post method as

```
var myArrayofModels = JSON.stringify(e.models);
this.collection.create(myArrayofModels );
```

Here `e.models` is an array of models which I convert to json and call Post method and I want to receive array of models on Post method like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(InsuranceAddressViewModel[] model)
{
    return null;
}
```

But I am getting null array in Post method. Is my method of converting array of models to json is fine or will have to do something else. I have tried couple of solutions but couldn't get idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879138/how-to-save-an-entire-collection-in-backbone-js-backbone-sync-or-jquery-ajax). Basically you store a collection inside a model and then override the toJSON method inside the model. A quick example can be seen below.

```
var ModelArray = Backbone.Model.extend({
  toJSON: function() {
     return this.collection.toJSON();
  }
});

var modelCollection = new ModelArray({ collection: collectionOfModels })

modelCollection.save();
```

Your controller should then pickup the properly formatted array of models you are trying to save.