# How to save collection of models in backbone.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I am using backbone in a project. I have a scenario where I have added my multiple models in a collection. Now i have array of models in the collection. I am using rest serivces in order to save. Now I want to make a post call to the server to save those array of models. I know there is a method to pass model to create method of collection like

```
this.collection.create(model)
```

But it is for single model to save. I had also tried to apply loop but it doesn't seem to work. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has been asked before. See for example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879138/how-to-save-an-entire-collection-in-backbone-js-backbone-sync-or-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [.add()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) function

```
this.collection.add(model);
this.colleciton.add([model1, model2, ..., modeln]);
```

Edit:

To save the models that are in the collection, you will need to write a function to iterate through them and save them all individually.

There are StackOverflow questions the answer this pretty well, for example:

["How" to save an entire collection in Backbone.js - Backbone.sync or jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879138/how-to-save-an-entire-collection-in-backbone-js-backbone-sync-or-jquery-ajax)

[Best practice for saving an entire collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014216/best-practice-for-saving-an-entire-collection)

[How to save a Collection with backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975316/how-to-save-a-collection-with-backbone-js)

Comment: okay I have added multiple models in my collection now what? How I will I make a post call to server ?